# How to learn MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I learn MathJax by looking at the source of a formula, whether it's here or in MathJax website. However, if the symbol I need cannot be found on the formulas I can find, then I'm stuck.

Any idea/ quick reference on MathJax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MathJax uses LaTeX syntax, so if you know how to typeset LaTeX equations, you know most of MathJax. See also [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117).

You could try [Detexify<sup>2</sup>](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) if there are symbols that you don't know the code (but note that not all symbols are supported in MathJax).